# AROSICS error ... RuntimeError: One of the input images does not have sufficient gray value information (non-no-data values)

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff

I am trying to use AROSICS package (https://danschef.git-pages.gfz-potsdam.de/arosics/doc/usage/input_data_requirements.html) to align an RBG image taken from a drone and a canopy height model extracted from lidar collect from the same drone.

When I run the code in Jupyter to align the two images an error occurs saying one of the images does not have sufficient 'gray value information' but I can't work out what the 'gray value information' is.

---

The code being run is found here: (https://danschef.git-pages.gfz-potsdam.de/arosics/doc/usage/global_coreg.html(

```
% from arosics import COREG

% im_reference = '/Path/to/canopy_height_model/chm.tif'

% im_target = '/Path/to/RGB_image/rgb.tif'

% CR = COREG(im_reference, im_target, wp=(683775, 9424525), ws=(1,-1))

% CR.calculate_spatial_shifts()
```

---

AROSICS error:

```
RuntimeError: One of the input images does not have sufficient gray value information (non-no-data values) for placing a matching window at the position (683775, 9424525). Matching failed.
```

---

Both files are .tif files - could this be the issue? The documentation states the file types supported (https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html) and includes GeoTIFF so maybe this isn't the issue.

---

I have tried removing no data values from the raster images but this didn't work.

Maybe a different file type will work but not sure what to convert the image and CHM to.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to a lack of contrast? Like all the same values in a window, that would make it impossible to match against something else.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the 'ws' value. I thought this was the pixel size but it was actually the pixel size of the search window. Therefore I changed this value back to default 'ws = (256, 256)'.